# Bootstrap 4 Flexbox Layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I want to create a layout like this [Layout Concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hsUD.png) with Bootstrap.

I try the following

```
<div class="h-100">
  <div class="bg-dark text-light d-flex flex-column">Header</div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-grow">
      <div class="bg-danger text-light w-25">Sidebar</div>
      <div class="w-75">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-dark text-light d-flex flex-column">Footer</div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bMVbxP)

The layout didn't get the full height even if html and body tags have height property 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's getting full height but the inner elements aren't. You may adjust classes like this:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="h-100 d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="bg-dark text-light p-3">Header</div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
      <div class="bg-danger text-light w-25">Sidebar</div>
      <div class="w-75">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-dark text-light p-3">Footer</div>
</div>
```